# Change button image on selection in custom table view cell

Tags: swift

I am beginner to Swift. I tried many tutorials but not helpful. I want to change button image of specific custom cell on selection.

Comment: Without any code I don't think you're gonna have much help. I suggest you to post the cell code, and, if relevant, the table code (such as `cellForRowAtIndexPatah`)

Comment: Hi, please state if @hardik.shah solution is resolving your issue, otherwise I will add others ways of solving this.

Comment: I already found a solution to my problem. This piece of code served the purpose. @IBAction func msgReadBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        msgReadBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "msg_read.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

Answer (score 1):

**Its very simple my friend**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
  //you got your cell now suppose your button tag is 3 
 var button:UIButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
 //you got you button now change the image of the button its done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3.0
//show a Arrow sign

```
cell2.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

//Change button image

```
    cell2.CheckBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage (named: "image name like "Govind""), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

its working